# Prestashop 1.7 Brand page doesn't include the sidebar

Tags: prestashop, sidebar, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on my installation of Prestashop 1.7 and I just realized that the brand/manufacturer page doesn't include the left sidebar with all the navigation filters. Is it a bug? How can be fixed? http://demo.prestashop.com/en/?view=front
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the brand page on your store doesn't have the sidebars enabled. You can fix that by going to the following page in your admin panel:

```
Design -> Theme & Logo -> Change Layouts
```